# How to put set inside an Intent as an extra?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a Set where the class Prova implements Serializable. I must put this Set in a intent. This is the code:

```
Set<Prova> set=..... // Set is declared first and it's not null
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Example.class);
intent.putExtra("set",set);
```

This code gives me: "cannot Resolve method". Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using `HashSet` instead of `Set` and then you can do something like this -

```
HashSet<Prova> set = new HashSet<>();
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Example.class);
intent.putExtra("mySet", set);;
```

`Set` itself does not implement `Serializable` but `HashSet` does and Intent can hold an instance of any class that implements Serializable or Parcelable.

Comment: this works only if the elements in the hashset are serializable